# JAXRS 2.0 Receive undefined number of parameters

Tags: java, json, jax-rs

I'm considering to expose a jaxrs method that receive a undefined number of parameters:

So, I'd like to be able to handle something like:

```
public class Foo {
    property1,
    property2,
    List<KeyValuePair> ...
}

public class KeyValuePair {
    String key,
    String value
}
```

Then,

```
@POST
public Response update(Foo document) {
    for (KeyValuePair pair : document.pairs)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I have no idea to achive this.
I'll appreciate a lot your help.
Thanks for all.

Comment: Is this for JSON.. XML... Both.. Something else? Also what JAX-RS implementation are you using?

Comment: Mainly JSON. My JEE aplication is using api libraries.The implementation depends of each container. Actually, my containers are WildFly 8.2 and GlassFish 4.1. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Mainly JSON. My JEE aplication is using api libraries.The implementation depends of each container. Actually, my containers are WildFly 8.2 and GlassFish 4.1.

<sup>**Note** this solution is only for JSON.</sup>

One way to handle this is to use Jackson's `@JsonAnySetter`. You can read more about it at [Jackson tips: using @JsonAnyGetter/@JsonAnySetter to create "dyna beans"](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_458.html). For example

```
@Path("json")
public class JsonResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response post(Model model) {
        return Response.ok(model).build();
    }

    public static class Model {

        public String name;
        private Map<String, Object> otherProps = new HashMap<>();

        @JsonAnySetter
        public void anyProps(String key, Object value) {
            otherProps.put(key, value);
        }

        @JsonAnyGetter
        public Map<String, Object> otherProps() {
            return otherProps;
        }
    }
}
```

Any properties on the `Model` that aren't `name`, are put into the `otherProps` map. This is due to the `@JsonAnySetter` annotation. The `@JsonAnyGetter` is just to ensure the the properties get marshalled.

To use this feature, the most portable way I can suggest to use it is to add this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Glassfish doesn't have this, so it doesn't conflict with anything. The only thing you need to do is disable the default deserializer (MOXy; trust me, you'll want to do this anyway - Jackson just *works* better). To disable MOXy in a portable way, you set the property. So in your `Application` class, you can have

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class JaxrsApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("jersey.config.disableMoxyJson", true);
        return properties;
    }
}
```

This is just a soft dependency, meaning there is no classes needed to use the property. It's simply a String. It will not affect any other containers you try to use it in. So you can leave the property for any container, even though is only strictly affects Glassfish.

In Wildfly, you don't really need to do anything else. The only "hardship" I would say is that if you port to Wildfly, you should just change the above Jackson dependency to a `provided` `<scope>`. Wildfly actually already uses this dependency, under the hood. So as not to conflict with it's version, we can simple mark it as `<scope>provided</scope>`. We cannot do this with Glassfish, as we *need* to include the jars into the build.

Comment: That was awesome! I'll test!