# Jackson serialise map with extra fields

Tags: java, json, jackson

If a class extends a Map and includes some extra fields. E.G a last modified date, Jackson seems to ignore any thing not contained as a property of the map.

I have a class that looks some thing like the following:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Objects;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Foo extends HashMap<String, String> {

   private OffsetDateTime lastModifiedTime;

   public Foo() {
      super();
      lastModifiedTime = OffsetDateTime.now();
   }

   public void setLastModifiedTime(OffsetDateTime newTime) {
      this.lastModifiedTime = newTime;
   }

   public OffsetDateTime getLastModifiedTime() {
      return this.lastModifiedTime;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      Foo f = new Foo();
      f.put("hello", "world");

      ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
      om.findAndRegisterModules();

      String result = om.writeValueAsString(f);
      if(f.equals(om.readValue(result, Foo.class))) {
         System.out.println("Wooo");
      } else {
         System.out.println("Booo: " + result);
      }

   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      if (this == obj) {
         return true;
      }
      if (!(obj instanceof Foo)) {
         return false;
      }
      if (!super.equals(obj)) {
         return false;
      }
      Foo foo = (Foo) obj;
      return Objects.equals(getLastModifiedTime(), foo.getLastModifiedTime());
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
      return Objects.hash(super.hashCode(), getLastModifiedTime());
   }

}
```

When this runs it outputs `booo: {"hello":"world"}` Which does not include the last modified date.

I've tried adding `@JsonInclude` annotations to the property and the getters but that doesn't cause it to include the extra field.

What is the correct way to make Jackson include this extra field?

Comment: Don't extend HashMap. Create a class that **has** a Map and an extra field instead of extending HashMap.

Comment: [For example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31307233/2587435)

Comment: @JBNizet Ah that works. Was hoping for an annotation to avoid needing to implement a number of extra methods (Size, empty, etc). If one of you wants to put it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: [Stolen!](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/1931)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's generally considered bad practice to extend HashMap. Instead, you should create a class that **has** a Map, and the additional field.

This will solve your problem, but will also have additional advantages:

- you will be able to encapsulate the rules (like preventing some keys/values to be added, etc.)
- you will be able to change the Map implementation if needed (LinkedHashMap, synchronized map, concurrent map)

Answer (score 7):

By default your map will fall into [`MapSerializer`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/MapSerializer.java). You could register a serializer modifier to add the custom property, but you would be better off nesting the map as a property of `Foo` and unwrapping it:

```
@JsonUnwrapped
private HashMap<String, String> fooMap;
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `@JsonUnwrapped`, you can use `@JsonAnyGetter` and `@JsonAnySetter` like this :

```
public class Foo {

   private OffsetDateTime lastModifiedTime;
   private HashMap<String, String> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, String>();

   public Foo() {
      super();
      lastModifiedTime = OffsetDateTime.now();
   }

   public void setLastModifiedTime(OffsetDateTime newTime) {
      this.lastModifiedTime = newTime;
   }

   public OffsetDateTime getLastModifiedTime() {
      return this.lastModifiedTime;
   }

   @JsonAnyGetter
   public Map<String, String> any() {
      return this.additionalProperties;
   }

   @JsonAnySetter
   public void set(String name, String value) {
      this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
   }
}
```

Comment: this is actually a good solution